# Java data encryption/decryption

Tags: java, mysql, security

I have a spring-mvc stack that stores data in MySQL. Some of this data needs to be protected, so I am thinking I should encrypt it.  Since I may need to use this data later (credit cards, SSN, other) so I will need to decrypt it.  I think this rules out hashing it.

There appear to be several approaches, including the Java crypto packages. Shiro appears to have some good capabilities, as does Blowfish-x.  And I see that MySQL supports encryption/decryption as well.  I am not sure I will be using MySQL for the long term.

My question is this: what is the best approach for a java application web based application to handle securely storing some of a users data?

Comment: You want to store credit card information in your database? Then PCI DSS is good standard for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to store secure data you have to ask yourself some basic questions :

- Do I have to keep the original data, or do only have to test its identity (=> use of hash algorithms)
- If I use encryption, how will I store my keys ?
- Will I need public key (asymmetric) cryptography (=> use of pki and certificates)

These are the main concerns to have.

Then, technically, the best way to implement it is a matter of what library you will have to choose.
Take a look at http://www.bouncycastle.org/.